# What happens when you shoot sand into a nether portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Currently I am playing [Minecraft Factions](https://mods.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/factions), and I'm trying to debate ways to make my chest room **un-raidable** from hybrid cannons. Now I've found out about regen chest, where you place lava over the top of them and water over an obsidian barrier and it will regen the cobblestone blocking off access to the chest for short periods of time.

But I wanna go a step further just because this method is not completely unraidable and I'm curious now as to what will happen if you try and launch sand into a nether portal. Will the sand remain in the overworld because there's **TNT** following behind it? Will the sand go into the nether because it counts as an entity?

Ultimately in terms of minecraft logic the sand should go threw the nether portal, what do you guys think? I've never seen a question or a video related to this topic so I thought I would bring it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is: The sand will go right through it.

While sand is moving through the air or falls down, it turns it into an entity, and when it stops moving, it is a normal block.

Every Entity except mobs is not able to go to the nether. That includes items, too.

Here is a GIF:

[image: TNT Sand Cannon]

Comment: Just to add to the answer. Sand is an entity, just like dropped items. Basically, anything that is an entity but not a mob cannot go through nether portals

Comment: Items are now able to go through nether portals, but it seems like falling blocks cannot. They can, however go through end portals.